# Pass compile options directly (bypassing CMakeLists.txt)

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Given the code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#ifdef MY_DEFINE
    printf("HERE\n");
#else
    printf("THERE\n");
#endif
}
```

To toggle `HERE` `THERE` behavior, I need the following in my `CMakeLists.txt

```
IF (${MY_DEFINE} MATCHES 1) # I want to remove these lines
    add_compile_options(-DMY_DEFINE)
ENDIF(${MY_DEFINE} MATCHES 1) # Up to here
```

Then, I can

`cmake -DMY_DEFINE=1` to get `HERE`

`cmake -DMY_DEFINE=0` to get `THERE`

This all seems a bit redundant...  Is it possible to remove those few lines in my CMakeLists.txt and still be able to get

`HERE` with something like `cmake -DMY_DEFINE=1`

`THERE` with just `cmake` or `cmake -DMY_DEFINE=0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `configure_file` command together with `#cmakedefine01` like so:

(contents of `configure.h.in`)

```
#cmakedefine01 MY_DEFINE
```

(in your CMakeLists.txt)

```
configure_file(configure.h.in configure.h @ONLY)
```

This will result in a `configure.h` in your build directory with the appropriate `#define` set. See the [configure_file documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) for a second example.

You can also use the CMake `option` command to expose the available options.
In your case, that would be:

```
option(MY_DEFINE "This configures whether you print HERE or THERE" OFF)
```